# Custom alignment with long equation and cases

Tags: math-mode, align, cases

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    x &= 1 & y &= 233 & z &= 3
    \\
    a &= 4 & c &= 5 & d &= 6
    \\
    & & K &= \begin{cases}
        10+a+b+c+d+e+f & \text{if condition X}
        \\
        -10+a-b+c+d+e+f & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases} & & 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

What I get

[image]

What I need

[image]

That is, the `K =`  with `cases` must be aligned with the `y =`  and `c =`  in the equations above, without pushing `z =`  and `d =`  to the right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{align}
    x &= 1 & y &= 233 & z &= 3\hspace{5cm}
    \\
    a &= 4 & c &= 5 & d &= 6
    \\
    & & K &= \begin{cases}
        10+a+b+c+d+e+f & \text{if condition X}
        \\
        -10+a-b+c+d+e+f & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}\hspace{-12cm} & &  
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The negative space after the cases is an arbitrary large amount to hide the width. The 5cm in the first line chosen by eye to leave space.